# dotplot with ggplot2 grouping the y values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data-set similar to this

```
products <- c('Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product3', 'Product1', 'Product1')
timestamp <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
categories <- c('Category1', 'Category2', 'Category1', 'Category1', 'Category1', 'Category1')
data <- data.frame(timestamp, products, categories)
```

Now I would like to draw a dotplot with ggplot2 like so

```
ggplot(data, aes(timestamp, products, colour=categories, group=categories)) + geom_point()
```

Which produces the following chart

[image]

Which is almost what I what, however, I would like to group the products in categories as they are in this chart:

```
dotchart(data$timestamp, labels=data$products, groups=data$categories, color=data$color)
```

[image]

It is important to plot occurrences of a product for the same y-value (like in the first plot), instead of repeating it for every record as it is done in the second plot.

Comment: is `+ facet_wrap(~categories)` useful to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try just making a new `y` column like so:

```
type <- paste(data$categories, data$products)
# convert to a factor and sort the levels reverse-alphabetical (so it is in order top-down on the plot)
type <- factor(type, levels=sort(unique(type), dec=T))
data$type <- type
ggplot(data, aes(timestamp, type, colour=categories)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

though the y axis text is not laid out like in the `dotchart`.

Or you could use `facet_wrap` for something similar but a bit different (don't need the `type` thing then):

```
ggplot(data, aes(timestamp, products, colour=categories)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ categories,ncol=1)
```

[image]

This one provides more separation of your categories and has the advantage (or perhaps disadvantage, depending on your opinion) of showing "empty" level combinations (e.g. category 2 product 1). If you don't like that add `scales="free_y"`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(timestamp, products, colour=categories)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ categories, ncol=1, scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to plot it in one chart? I have a rather huge dataset.

Comment: The first option is in one chart.

Comment: If all you want to do is remove the vertical whitespace on the last option, do a `+ theme(panel.margin=unit(0, 'lines'))` (you also need `library(grid)` to get to `unit`).  As for vertical spacing between the y axis lines (between Product 3 and Product 1 for example), if you squish your plot window vertically these will also squish together.

Comment: sorry about that, the first chart is exactly what I was looking for :) little overwhelmed by the extend of your skill :D